# Proving (or disproving) that the sine and cosine of integers are always unique

Tags: trigonometry

Can it be proven that

$ \forall x, y \in \mathbb{Z} \left( \sin(x) = \sin(y) \iff x = y\right)$

? Or disproven, of course. And likewise with cosine?

Since sine and cosine have periods of $2\pi$, for $x$ and $y$ radians to have the same location on the unit circle, $x$ and $y$ would have to differ by  $2k\pi$ radians, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

How can I show that there exists no $k$ such that $y - 2k\pi = x$, given $x, y, k \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: It's not true that if $\sin(x)=\sin(y)$ then $x$ and $y$ differ by $2k\pi$ radians.

Comment: It comes down to proving that $\pi$ is irrational, or, more likely, quoting the result. What you need is an easy consequence.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. I forgot about $y = \pi - x$ and the similar, negative quadrant version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. It should be clear why $\forall x,y\in\Bbb{Z}$, $x=y\implies\sin(x)=\sin(y)$. It remains to prove the converse: $\forall x,y\in\Bbb{Z}$, $\sin(x)=\sin(y)\implies x=y$

We proceed by contradiction. Suppose instead that there exist integers $x,y$ such that $\sin(x)=\sin(y)$ yet $x\neq y$. Then, as you figured out, there are only $2$ possibilities:

**Case 1:** Suppose that $y=x+(2\pi)k$ for some nonzero $k\in \Bbb{Z}$. Then solving for $\pi$, we obtain:
$$
\pi=\dfrac{y-x}{2k}
$$
Since $x,y,k\in\Bbb{Z}$ where $k\neq0$, it follows that $\pi \in \Bbb{Q}$, a contradiction.

**Case 2:** Suppose that $y=(\pi-x)+(2\pi)k$ for some  $k\in \Bbb{Z}$. Then solving for $\pi$, we obtain:
$$
\pi=\dfrac{y+x}{1+2k}
$$
Since $x,y,k\in\Bbb{Z}$ where $k\neq-1/2$, it follows that $\pi \in \Bbb{Q}$, a contradiction.

In either case, we obtained a contradiction. Hence, we have proven the converse, as desired.